# Phasor diagram in Android

Tags: android, diagram, android-graphview

Can we draw phasor diagram in Android, I googled a lot and didn't find any help. In my project I need to draw sine waveform, table, bar graph an Android, I completed all the 3 diagrams using graphview library but didn't find any source for drawing phasor diagram in Android.

[image: Phasor Diagram]

Can we achieve this diagram through SurfaceView or Canvas in android or through any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i achieved my Phasor Diagram  through **SurfaceView**. I drew Lines directly into a **Canvas** which works as a interface, to the actual surface upon which your graphics will be drawn,  it holds all of your "draw" calls. I Used **Paint** class to draw line on canvas. Paint class holds the style and color information about how to draw geometries, text and bitmaps.[image]